# How to populate dropdown from a json file?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

json file has...

```
{
"OrderTypeList": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "orderType": "XYZ"
},
...
```

}

component code:

```
  orderTypes: any[];

  getOrderTypes() { 
   this.OrderService.getJsonData('./assets/OrderTypes.json').subscribe((data:any[]) => {
        this.orderTypes = data;
  }); 
  }
```

The drop-down component shows the entire json object in one line?! I only want order types.

```html
<select name="types" id="#" *ngFor="let ot of orderTypes | keyvalue">
    <option selected="selected" value="one">{{ot.value | json}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: please specify what are the requirements, at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include `*ngFor` on the `<option>` tag and use string interpolation to get the attribute you want from the object. You don't need the pipe json in your case. You can check if the attribute of your object is an array, if it is you can iterate over it `orderTypes[ot.key])` on the second `*ngFor`

An example:

HTML:

```
<!-- First example with pipe 'keyvalue' -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let ot of orderTypes | keyvalue">
  <ng-container *ngIf="ot.key === 'orders'">

    <select name="types" id="#">
      <option 
        selected="selected" 
        value="one"
        *ngFor="let order of orderTypes[ot.key]">
          {{ ot.key }} => {{ order.orderType }}
      </option>
    </select>

  </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<br /><br />

<!-- Second example with array -->
<select name="types" id="#">
  <option 
    selected="selected" 
    value="one"
    *ngFor="let order of orderTypes.orders">
      {{ order.orderType }}
  </option>
</select>
```

TS:

```
orderTypes = {
  id: 1,
  orders: [  
    {
      id: 1,
      orderType: "XYZ"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      orderType: "ABC"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      orderType: "ZXC"
    }
  ]
};
```

Here's a stackblitz with the two:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3pgerp?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried. It shows empty dropdown. I also see below error in the console. "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: Make sure that the variable you passed to *ngFor is an array. 
Here's an example on stackblitz with the same code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3pgerp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I understand that part. That's the reason I have tried with keyvalue in the html to avoid that error. What's wrong in my component code? Should I do any to convert to an array? Thanks much.

Comment: Sorry, now i understand, i guess. I edited the code on stackblitz and the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. why is this need to be complicated? Also, it prints all the value in one line, I'd like to have 3 values in my dropdown.

Comment: I updated the response and the stackblitz again. I think it gets complicated based on the keyvalue pipe with an array inside its properties. A put two solutions, the first one is with what you need and the second one is more simple, but i dont know if it helps you.

The stackblitz was updated too